# connect master server stream_socket_client

Tags: php, sockets

I wrote a script to pull a server list from the master server from Enemy Territory; However it silently fails; I had it working; but for some unknown reason it doesn't anymore.

I used this document to "talk" with the server : http://src.gnu-darwin.org/ports/games/masterserver/work/masterserver-0.4.1/docs/PROTOCOLS
This seems valid since it worked before and it still works on game servers; This is my code :

```
<?php
// set sv_master1 "etmaster.idsoftware.com"
// set sv_master2 "master0.gamespy.com"
// set sv_master3 "wolfmaster.idsoftware.com"
// set sv_master4 "clanservers.net"
// set sv_master5 "master0.etmaster.net" 213.108.29.23

$host = 'etmaster.idsoftware.com';
$port = '27950';
// $status = chr(255) . chr(255) . chr(255) . chr(255) . chr(0x02) .  'getservers' . chr(0x00);
$status = "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFFgetservers\x00";

$fp = stream_socket_client("udp://" . $host . ":" . $port, $errno, $errstr, 10);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "ERROR: " . $errno . $errstr . "<br>\n";
} else {

    fwrite($fp, $status);
    //stream_set_timeout($fp, 10); // this is for debugging;
    $data = fread($fp, 1024);
    fclose($fp);

    print_r($data);     
}
```

I attempted 60 seconds execution time (its localhost) but it still doesn't work ... any help is appreciated !

When I check the steps (in cli) the longest time is spend on fread(); but $data contains only an empty string;

Comment: print_r($data); should return bogus text, since this is 6byte encoded seperated by '/' (ip : 4 byte, port : 2 byte)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is small; there had to be 5* \xFF tag; and I only used 4.